# Setting reference grid to map layout on ISO A4 page template in ArcMap but grid is not fitting to data frame

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, grids-graticules

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

I have attached both the screenshots of the map layouts. When I am working with a previously saved Map Layout which I created in ArcMap 10.5, the grid is showing in proper margin.

How can I sort out this problem?

[[image: Screenshot of the faulty map layout]

Comment: How many data frames can you see in your Table of Contents?

Comment: That does not look like a reference grid, it looks like a graticule.

Comment: Going from 10.5 to 10.8.1...I'd just recreate the layout from scratch, particularly if it's just the data frame with a reference grid and/or graticule.

Comment: @PolyGeo, Thanks for your early response. In the attachment you saw that was only one data frame I had added. But on adding reference grid, only the left side is sitting outside the data frame but all other three sides are sitting inside the data frame. Even when I add the map title aligning to the center, its not exactly setting to the center for which I need to manually adjust it. Please ask more if you want to understand the issue.

Comment: @Dan, Thanks for the response. But Scratch is not showing in AG10.8.1 version. What to do? Can you please provide any solution to the issue?

Comment: Is the highlighted layout element your one and only data frame, or is it something else like a neatline?

Comment: @PolyGeo, The highlighted one is the data frame.

Comment: What I meant was start a new layout in ArcMap 10.8.1 instead of trying to use the one from the 10.5 mxd.  Also check to see if the grid that was created in 10.5 was converted to a graphic.  If it was, then it will not adjust automatically when the data frame is moved/changed.

Comment: @PolyGeoThanks for the suggestion here. I do know this technique. But it really doesn't solve the actual problem.